# using struct in c++ to represent buffer format

Tags: c++

New to C++. I have this function 'Process' which takes 'in_buf' of generally one 16 byte of data but I am writing this new lineInterleaved class which takes this 'interleave_buf' format. Wondering if this way of representing format is the best way to code this in c++?

```
struct interleave_buf {
        int32_t data_1_[8][128];
        int32_t data_2_[2][128];
        int16_t data_3_[128];
        int16_t index;
};

class lineInterleaved : public sp_line_t {
        public:
        virtual int Process(const void* in_buf, 
                size_t* in_sample_count,
                void* out_buf,  
                size_t* out_sample_count);
        private:
                struct interleave_buf buffer;
}


int lineInterleaved::Process(const void* in_buf, size_t* bytes, void* out_buf, size_t* out_sample_count) {
        if (in_buf == NULL || bytes == NULL) {
                return -EINVAL;
        }

        int8_t* out = static_cast<int8_t*>(out_buf);
        const int8_t* in = static_cast<const int8_t*>(in_buf);
        memcpy(buffer.data_1_, in, sizeof(buffer.data_1_));
        memcpy(buffer.data_2_, in + sizeof(buffer.data_1_), sizeof(buffer.data_2_));
        memcpy(buffer.data_3_, in + sizeof(buffer.data_1_) + sizeof(buffer.data_2_), sizeof(buffer.data_3_));
        memcpy(out, in + sizeof(buffer.data_1_) + sizeof(buffer.data_2_), sizeof(buffer.data_3_));
        *out_sample_count = sizeof(buffer.data_3_);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question or issue we can help you with?  You have posted a bunch of code but no specific problem to solve.

Comment: I just want to know if this is the best way to  code in c++?

Comment: It depends what you exactly do, `memcpy`, `int32_t data_1_[8][128]`, `const void*`, ... can be fine, if you really need to use them for interactions with foreign libraries or on a hardware level.  But then a comment is missing why you use `memcpy` instead of `std` functions,  `int32_t data_1_[8][128]` instead of `std::array`, ... . In the current state, it looks like an unmaintainable error-prone code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to copy buffer to struct, assigning a pointer to buffer is the efficient way to parse buffer into struct.

so instead of all `memcpy`s you just assign the ponter to the buffer, 
For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
struct clsA
{
    char a1[10];
    char a2[10];
};

void f(const void *buf)
{
    const clsA *pA = static_cast<const clsA*>(buf);
    cout << pA->a1 <<endl;
    cout << pA->a2 <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    char buf[30];
    strcpy(buf,"xx");
    strcpy(&buf[10],"yy");
    f(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Unless you want to save the data you won't copy it, and if you want to copy the struct you can use regular assignment:

```
clsA b = *pA;
```

Another issue, using pointers for out parameter is C style, in C++ the common way is to use by reference vars for this manner.

So your process method should be:

```
int lineInterleaved::Process(const void* in_buf, size_t bytes, void* out_buf, size_t& out_sample_count)
```

- You should use by value for IN parameters only for basic types.
- You should use const reference for IN parameters for complex types (classes, structs).
- You should use by ref just for OUT or IN\OUT parameters.

Comment: I have to use memcpy because the memory passed is a local buffer memory.

Comment: @avltree: You don't have to use memcpy, because `clsA b = *pA` as shown in this answer will do the equivalent copy in a nicer way.